# Get the bounding box of the visible leaflet map?

Tags: leaflet

I have a leaflet map that pans and zooms. How can I dynamically get the lat/long of the edges of the map (after zooming in/out + panning)?

Comment: Do you mean the bounds/extents of the map? Or every lat long that runs around the border of the extents? If you just want to get the bounds you can call a map.getBounds() on dragend. map.on('dragend', myFunctionThatGetsMapBounds()) I would try something like this for getting the bounds every time the map is moved. Same can be done for  zoomend.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

It is, as you may guess:

```
map.getBounds();
```

If you want to get the bounds after panning and zooming, use [events](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-events), like

```
map.on('moveend', function() { 
     alert(map.getBounds());
});
```

Comment: for more information about getBounds, it returns a LatLngBounds.
Methods and props there : https://www.wrld3d.com/wrld.js/latest/docs/leaflet/L.LatLngBounds/

Answer (score 31):

The above answer is correct, but it doesn't shed much light on what is happening as values change. Unfortunately, the leaflet docs don't give much detail about the getBounds() call.

Here is a slightly more elaborate call that will give you a more detailed picture. If you add this to your map init function, you can see the map data displayed:

```js
map.on('dragend', function onDragEnd(){
    var width = map.getBounds().getEast() - map.getBounds().getWest();
    var height = map.getBounds().getNorth() - map.getBounds().getSouth();

    alert (
        'center:' + map.getCenter() +'\n'+
        'width:' + width +'\n'+
        'height:' + height +'\n'+
        'size in pixels:' + map.getSize()
    )});
```

Note that size is the pixel dimensions of the map window, where the bounds are the scaled internal sizes. Try zooming and you will see that the size stays constant, but the height and with doubles for each level of zoom.

There are a whole bunch of methods that live under the LatLngBounds object, so you should be able to find one of the calls there that can give you whatever info you are looking for.

Comment: the former answer was concise.