# Getting bounding box from leaflet in R

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I am using R, RStudio and the `leaflet` package to visualise a map.

I would like to get the the min and max lat-longs of of the bounding box of a leaflet object. I think this can be done using Shiny (by using something like `input$mapobj_bounds`) but is there a non-shiny method to do this.

```
m <- leaflet(width=500,height=400) %>% 
   addTiles() %>% 
   setView(lng = -0.106831, lat = 51.515328, zoom = 18) %>%
   addCircleMarkers(lng = -0.106831, lat = 51.515328)
```

What i need is a function to get the bounding box using the input argument `m`.

Can this be done?

Also, the parameter values when looking into the object `m` look incorrect.

e.g.

```
> m$x$limits
$lat
[1] 51.51533 51.51533

$lng
[1] -0.106831 -0.106831
```

*EDIT*

I think the javascript function `map.getBounds()` may be of help here...as suggested here ([Get the bounding box of the visible leaflet map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22948096/get-the-bounding-box-of-the-visible-leaflet-map?rq=1)), but do not know how to apply this to our problem. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: yes i also posted a solution with `map.getBounds()` an hour ago but deleted it as i didnt find a way to return the values as R variables. I only managed to produce popups :) I can undelete it if you like. Concerning a function f(m) that returns the bounds to R, i think one would need the ratio scales for the zoom levels, like there exists for google maps: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7430/what-ratio-scales-do-google-maps-zoom-levels-correspond-to. But i didnt find it for leaflet,..

Comment: Could they be written to csv as an output from an html once the object has been saved?? But yes please un-delete the answer as i would be keen to learn more javascript too

Comment: The results of map.getBounds() (as demonstrated nicely by @BigDataScientist) change as you resize the Viewer window. This indicates that the bounding box does not depend entirely on your `m` object. Even if you were able to output the result from the html, it would only give you the results for that particular browser and it's settings.

Answer (score 10):

If you adapt Jeremys original answer a bit you can actually do it without javascript:

**Reproducible example:**

```
library(magrittr)
library(leaflet)

m <- leaflet(width = 500,height = 400) %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  setView(lng = -0.106831, lat = 51.515328, zoom = 18) %>%
  addCircleMarkers(lng = -0.106831, lat = 51.515328)
m
getBox <- function(m){
  view <- m$x$setView
  lat <- view[[1]][1]
  lng <- view[[1]][2]
  zoom <- view[[2]]
  zoom_width <- 360 / 2^zoom
  lng_width <- m$width / 256 * zoom_width
  lat_height <- m$height / 256 * zoom_width
  return(c(lng - lng_width/2, lng + lng_width/2, lat - lat_height/2, lat + lat_height/2))
}
getBox(m)
```

In **shiny** you can simply you use: input$MAPID_bounds

**Reproducible example:**

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(magrittr)

app <- shinyApp(

  ui = fluidPage(leafletOutput('myMap')),

  server = function(input, output) {

    output$myMap = renderLeaflet({
      leaflet() %>% 
        addTiles() %>% 
        setView(
          lng = 50, 
          lat = 10, 
          zoom = 17
        )
    })

    observeEvent(input$myMap_bounds, {
      print(input$myMap_bounds)
    })

  }
)
```

for more info see here: https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shiny.html.

Here a javscript version (initial workaround). For the better version, see above.

```
  leaflet() %>% addTiles()  %>% 
  setView(lng = -0.106831, lat = 51.515328, zoom = 18) %>%
  addEasyButton(easyButton(
    states = list(
      easyButtonState(
        stateName="unfrozen-markers",
        icon="ion-toggle",
        title="Get Bounding box",
        onClick = JS("
                     function(btn, map) {
                        alert(map.getBounds().getEast());
                        alert(map.getBounds().getWest());
                        alert(map.getBounds().getNorth());
                        alert(map.getBounds().getSouth());
                     }")
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @BigDataScientist's answer for pointing out, that width & height are available!

It is possible to calculate the bounding boxes, as long as you know the leaflet widget's dimensions. See [leafletjs.com/examples/zoom-levels](http://leafletjs.com/examples/zoom-levels)

Given that this is specified with `leaflet(width=500,height=400)`, this will work.

```
if (is.null(m$width) | is.null(m$height)) {
    print("Leaflet width and height must be speciied")
} else {
       width <- m$width 
       height <- m$height 
       zoom <- m$x$setView[[2]]
       lng <- m$x$setView[[1]][2]
       lat <- m$x$setView[[1]][1]
       lng_width <- 360 * width / 2^(zoom + 8)
       lng_east <- lng - lng_width/2
       lng_west <- lng + lng_width/2
       lat_height <- 360 * height * cos(lat/180 * pi) / 2^(zoom + 8)
       lat_north <- lat + lat_height/2
       lat_south <- lat - lat_height/2
}

> lng_east
[1] -0.1081721
> lng_west
[1] -0.1054899
> lat_north
[1] 51.516
> lat_south
[1] 51.51466
```

Comparing to @BigDataScientist, this gives the same answer as `map.getBounds` to 3 decimal places.

[image]

**EDIT**
I based my answer on the documentation from leaflet referenced. It would seem that this is a simplification. I have added the `cos(lat/180 * pi)` term which improves accuracy. For example, this now gives north-boundary of 51.516, which is only a difference of 0.0000029 from leaflet's 51.51599707.

I have tested this at a few different latitudes and zooms. Accuracy decreases at lower zoom levels.

Comment: you could use m$height and m$width given the m in the question. See the edit in my post, if its unclear. Feel free to add it to your answer, you were the one coming incredibly close to it :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I was so obsessed with finding the viewer pane's dimensions, I missed that width and height of leaflet were specified in the original question!

Comment: it also took me a while, as i made my own small leaflet map for testing and did not specify width and length in there.

Comment: I've done some further testing. I managed to improve the accuracy, but there is more work needed at lower zoom levels.

Comment: Thank you for the additional accuracy by using the cos term...can you please explain the `zoom + 8` part please?

Comment: I simplified the calculation. Part of which was dividing by (256 x 2^zoom). As 256 = 2^8, this becomes 2^8 x 2^zoom = 2^(zoom + 8)

Comment: It should be possible to increase accuracy further, if someone has time,  by reverse engineering leaflet.js to see exactly how they do the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but it recently [29 Apr 2022] assisted me in finding a solution to a problem I was faced with. To say thanks I combined the approaches of `@TonioLiebrand` and `@JeremyVoisey` into a single self-contained (neatly rounded-off) function as follows:

```
# Self-contained function to calculate 'Leaflet Map Widget' Bounding Box co-ordinates ...
"f.calc.leaflet.bounding.box.coords" <- function(objLeafletMap=NULL) {
  FUNC_ID_SHORT <- "fCLBBC"; FUNC_ID_FULL <- "f.calc.leaflet.bounding.box.coords";
  boundNorth_ <- NULL; boundWest_ <- NULL; boundSouth_ <- NULL; boundEast_ <- NULL;
  if (is.null(objLeafletMap) || is.null(objLeafletMap$width) || is.null(objLeafletMap$height)) {
    base::message(base::paste0(" --> ", FUNC_ID_SHORT, " - Line 4 ", "| LEAFLET MAP WIDTH & HEIGHT NOT SPECIFIED ( FUNC ID: '", FUNC_ID_FULL, "' )."))
    base::stop(base::paste0(" --> ", FUNC_ID_SHORT, " - Line 5 ", " | Function Execution Terminated [ reason: REQUIRED PARAMS are NULL ] !!"))
  } else {        
    # Extract Leaflet Map Widget 'x' property list values ( i.e. [center 'lat' & 
    # 'lon'], 'zoom' and 'options' widget property values )...
    view_ <- objLeafletMap$x$setView; zoom_ <- view_[[2]]; 
    lon_ <- view_[[1]][2]; lat_ <- view_[[1]][1];
    
    # Extract Leaflet Map Widget 'width' and 'height' values ...
    width_ <- objLeafletMap$width; height_ <- objLeafletMap$height;
    
    # Calculate Leaflet Map Widget peripheral extent in co-ordinate dimensions ...
    lon_width_ <- 360 * width_ / 2 ^ (zoom_ + 8);
    lat_height_ <- 360 * height_ * cos(lat_ / 180 * base::pi) / 2 ^ (zoom_ + 8);
    
    # Calculate Leaflet Map Widget peripheral extent ( i.e. Bounding Box ) in co-ordinate values ...
    boundEast_ <- lon_ + lon_width_ / 2; boundWest_ <- lon_ - lon_width_ / 2;
    boundNorth_ <- lat_ + lat_height_ / 2; boundSouth_ <- lat_ - lat_height_ / 2;
  }
  return(list(top=boundNorth_, right=boundEast_, bottom=boundSouth_, left=boundWest_, zoom=zoom_))
}
```

This might be a bit of an overkill for some, but might also be a boon for others looking for a quick [time-critical] solution (as I did). Simply copy & paste the function into your R script, and once the function is read into your R Session Memory extract your Leaflet Map Widget bounding co-ordinates as follows:

```
# Simply call the function from wherever you need in your R script ...
mapBounds <- f.calc.leaflet.bounding.box.coords(m);   # <- 'm' == Leaflet Map Widget (with 'width' and 'height' defined) !!


# ... and extract the results as follows:
mapBounds$top
> -5.83050217387398

mapBounds$right
> 38.25046875 

mapBounds$bottom
> -40.209497826126 

mapBounds$left
> -9.21046875
```

I also added the `zoom` value as an output (because it seems ***wasteful to compute*** it inside the function ***but not return*** it [as a result] to the function call). So now you can easily easily get the `zoom` value by calling ...

```
mapBounds$zoom
> 5
```

... `after every map zoom change` - if you really, ***really*** need to do that.

Lastly, I concur with `@JeremyVoisey`, there is an accuracy issue with the results from this approach - but this code snippet was sufficient in resolving the problem I had (and I was a bit time-pressed) ... so I didn't look into fixing the accuracy issue at the time.