# How can I tell if a Leaflet layer is currently visible?

Tags: leaflet, gis, esri, esri-leaflet, esri-oss

I'm building a Leaflet plugin that adds/removes layers to/from a Leaflet map. My plugin needs to know if a given layer is visible on-screen. So far, I've come up with the following criteria that a layer must meet in order to be considered "visible":

- It must be added to the map. (This is [trivial to check](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#map-haslayer) in my case.)
- It must be within a valid zoom range. (This is also [pretty easy to handle](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#map-getzoom).)
- **It must be visible within the current extent/bounds.**

The third criteria is the one I am having difficulty checking. My layers are a variety of different [Esri-Leaflet](http://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/) layers. I understand that I can check whether a given point or rectangle is contained within the visible bounds of the map with `map.getBounds().contains(...)`, but my problem is I am not sure how to represent my Esri-Leaflet layer as a rectangle. Not even all Leaflet layers have a [`getLatLng()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#marker-getlatlng) method, so this question isn't even Esri-Leaflet specific (e.g. how would you perform the same check on a [TileLayer](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#tilelayer))?

**How can I get the bounds of a Leaflet layer, or otherwise check if the layer is visible on the map?**

Not a duplicate of:

- [Get a list of markers/layers within current map bounds in Leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22081680/get-a-list-of-markers-layers-within-current-map-bounds-in-leaflet)
- [Get the bounding box of the visible leaflet map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22948096/get-the-bounding-box-of-the-visible-leaflet-map)

Comment: I think some leaflet plugins like markerclusterer do optimizations to hide elements that are not visible in the current bounds. Maybe you could look there for ideas.

Comment: I'm looking for something fairly similar, and I've got turf.js in my back pocket.  If you turn the bound into a rectangle polygon, you can probably check if they have any ovelaps